# Convergent sequence in Range has convergent premimage for a surjective bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear surjective operator where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $y\in Y$. Then for $\{y_n\}$ converging to $y$,  $\exists \{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ s.t. $T(x)=y$.

Edit: I meant there exists a convergent $\{x_n\}$ such that $T(x_n)=y_n$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: The question is not properly stated, What is the connection between $y_n$ and $x_n$? We can take $x$ such that $Tx=y$ and then take $x_n=x$ for all $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited the question as it was not properly stated before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an application of the open mapping theorem. In particular a useful proposition is the following:

> If $T:X\to Y$ is a surjection bounded linear operator between the two Banach space $X,Y$, then, there is exists a constant $M>0$ such that for every $y\in Y$ there is some $x\in X$ with $Tx=y$ and $||x||\leq M||y||$.

To prove this, from the open mapping theorem there is some $M'>0$ such that $M'B_Y\subseteq T(B_X)$ (i.e. $0$ belongs to the interior of $T(B_X)$), where $B_X=\{x\in X:\ ||x||\leq 1\}$ denotes the closed unit ball of $X$. Equivalently, $$\tag{1}B_Y\subseteq \frac{1}{M'}T(B_X)$$

Now pick $y\neq 0$ in $Y$. Then $y/||y||\in B_Y$, so from $(1)$ there is some $x'\in B_X$ such that $$\frac{1}{M'}Tx'=\frac{y}{||y||}$$

Then $T(\frac{||y||x'}{M'})=y$. Setting $x=\frac{||y||x'}{M'}$ we have $Tx=y$ and $||x||\leq \frac{1}{M'}||y||$. So if we pick $M=1/M'$ we have proved the above proposition. Now its easy to prove what you want since if $y_n\to y$. Then, fix some $x\in X$ with $Tx=y$.

Then use the proposition for the element $y_n-y$ and find $z_n\in X$ such that $Tz_n=y_n-y$ and $$\tag{2}||z_n||\leq M||y_n-y||$$

Then by $(2)$ it follows that $z_n\to 0$. Take $x_n=z_n+x$.

Comment: Why is it equivalent $T(B_X(0,1))$ being open to the existence of $M'>0$ such that $M'B_Y(0,1)\subseteq T(B_X(0,1))$?

Comment: @dem0nakos I would just point out a minor correction, $\frac{y}{||y||}\notin B_Y(0,1)$ if you are considering the open ball $B_Y(0,1)$. But this can be easily managed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SatwataHans Yes you are right, i thought about it when i was writing the answer and then i wanted to change the notation of $B_X(0,1)$ which is being used for the open ball, to $B_X=\{x\in X:\ ||x||\leq 1\}$ but i forgot it. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @Darsen $T(B_X(0,1))$ is open in $Y$ ( open mapping theorem ). $0\in T(B_X(0,1))$. So there is $M_1>0$ such that $M_1B_Y(0,1)=B_Y(0,M_1)\subseteq T(B_X(0,1))$. Pick $0<M'<M_1$. Then $M'B_Y=M'\overline{B_Y(0,1)}\subseteq M_1B_Y(0,1)\subseteq T(B_X(0,1))\subseteq T(B_X)$.

Comment: @dem0nakos Changing $B_X(0,1)$ to the closed unit ball won't help, as then, $T(B_X(0,1))$ need not be open. Your problem will be solved if you just take $B_X(0,1+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @SatwataHans Its not open but $0$ belongs to the interior of $T(B_X(0,1))$ where $B_X(0,1)$ is the open ball and $T(B_X(0,1))$ is a subset of $T(B_X)$ where $B_X$ is the closed unit ball. That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution without using the open mapping theorem. We have that $M:=E/\ker T\cong F$ by the mapping $\tilde T[x] = Tx$, therefore a convergent sequence $(y_n)_n \subset F$, let's say $y_n \to y_0 = Tx_0$, produces a convergent sequence in $M$, $[x_n]\to [x_0]$. This means that given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $N$ such that for very $n\ge N$
$$\varepsilon >\| [x_n]-[x_0]\|_M:= \inf \{\|x_n-x_0-z \|_X : \, z\in \ker T\}$$
That means that for each $n\geq N$ there is a $z_n \in \ker T$ for which $\|x_n-x_0-z_n\| < \varepsilon$. However, we found the $z_n$ for the given epsilon, therefore the sequence $(x_n-z_n)$ does not necessarily converge to $x_0$.

Consider $\frac{1}{k}\to 0$. For every $k$ we can repeat the process above and find $z_n^k$ that verifies $\|x_n-x_0-z^k_n\| < \frac{1}{k}$ for all $n\geq N_k$. Do it for $k=1$, then for $k=2$ keep all $z^1_n$ for which the inequality is still valid and find new ones for the rest. Repeat the process for every $k$. We end up with a sequence $x_n-w_n$, where $w_n$ is a $z_n^k$ for a certain $k$. Now, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}< \varepsilon$ and for that $k$ there is a $N_k$ such that if $n\geq N_K$ then $\| x_n-w_n -x_0\| < \frac{1}{k}<\varepsilon$. Therefore, $x_n -w_n \to x_0$.

Since $w_n\in \ker T$ for all $n$, additionally we have that $T(x_n-w_n) = Tx_n = y_n$ as we wanted to prove.